# ACID transactions on data added from Spark not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to use ACID transactions in Hive but I have a problem when the data are added with Spark.

First, I created a table with the following statement :

```
CREATE TABLE testdb.test(id string, col1 string)
CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 4 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

Then I added data with those queries :

```
INSERT INTO testdb.test VALUES("1", "A");
INSERT INTO testdb.test VALUES("2", "B");
INSERT INTO testdb.test VALUES("3", "C");
```

And I've been able to delete rows with this query :

```
DELETE FROM testdb.test WHERE id="1";
```

All that worked perfectly, but a problem occurs when I try to delete rows that were added with Spark.

What I do in Spark (iPython) :

```
hc = HiveContext(sc)
data = sc.parallelize([["1", "A"], ["2", "B"], ["3", "C"]])
data_df = hc.createDataFrame(data)
data_df.registerTempTable(data_df)
hc.sql("INSERT INTO testdb.test SELECT * FROM data_df");
```

Then, when I come back to Hive, I'm able to run a SELECT query on this the "test" table.
However, when I try to run the exact same DELETE query as before, I have the following error (it happens after the reduce phase) :

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":0}},"value":null}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":0}},"value":null}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:253)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:723)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
... 7 more
```

I have no idea where this is coming from, that is why I'm looking for ideas.

I'm using the Cloudera Quickstart VM (5.4.2). 
Hive version : 1.1.0 
Spark Version : 1.3.0

And here is the complete output of the Hive DELETE command :

```
hive> delete from testdb.test where id="1";

Query ID = cloudera_20160914090303_795e40b7-ab6a-45b0-8391-6d41d1cfe7bd
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 4
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1473858545651_0036, Tracking URL =http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1473858545651_0036/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1473858545651_0036
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 4
2016-09-14 09:03:55,571 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-09-14 09:04:14,898 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.66 sec
2016-09-14 09:04:15,944 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 3.33 sec
2016-09-14 09:04:44,101 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 4.21 sec
2016-09-14 09:04:46,523 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 25%, Cumulative CPU 4.79 sec
2016-09-14 09:04:47,673 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 42%, Cumulative CPU 5.8 sec
2016-09-14 09:04:50,041 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 75%, Cumulative CPU 7.45 sec
2016-09-14 09:05:18,486 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 7.69 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 7 seconds 690 msec
Ended Job = job_1473858545651_0036 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1473858545651_0036/
Examining task ID: task_1473858545651_0036_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1473858545651_0036

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1473858545651_0036_r_000001

URL:
http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1473858545651_0036&tipid=task_1473858545651_0036_r_000001
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":0}},"value":null}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":0}},"value":null}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:253)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:723)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
... 7 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 2  Reduce: 4   Cumulative CPU: 7.69 sec   HDFS Read: 21558 HDFS Write: 114 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 7 seconds 690 msec
```

Thanks !

Comment: Spark uses its own ORC and Parquet SerDe by default, and from what you show, the resulting ORC output has clearly not been tested against the Hive "transactional" ORC SerDe. There is a Spark option to force it to use the Hive Parquet SerDe instead -- but unfortunately, AFAIK there is no similar option for ORC.

Comment: You should try again with the latest Cloudera distro -- it now supports an experimental release of **Hive-on-Spark** (using Spark 1.6.0-plus-some-backports) so, hopefully, they did a better job of supporting transactions than in that old V1.3 you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I think that I will have to find a workaround because I cannot use Hive-on-Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spark HiveAcid Datasource - http://github.com/qubole/spark-acid

```
 val df = spark.read.format("HiveAcid").option("table", "testdb.test").load()
 df.collect()
```

Spark needs to run with HMS 3.1.1 so that the underlying datasource can take necessary locks etc.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure, file formats are different for a Hive ACID table compared with a normal table. CRUD needs to happen from Hive.

With respect to Spark, normal table reads are not compatible with Hive ACID table reads. We could not use the native Spark apis to read the table.
Also, currently there is no support for updates, deletes, inserts in Spark
As for reading the data,  one could use the connector - http://github.com/qubole/spark-acid

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running from hue, but after I set these parameters from hive cli, it started working:

```
set hive.support.concurrency=true
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DBTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
```